# Concatenate excel files with all their sheets Python

Tags: python, concatenation, worksheet

I have two excel files with the same name saved under different directories, the first file has two sheets `Rapport détaillé`  and `Délai de reconnection` and the second file has one sheet named `Rapport détaillé`.

I need to concatenate these two files:

1. Concatenate the sheets with the same name
2. Keep the second sheet from the first file

so the output excel file needs to have two sheets, the first is `Rapport détaillé` and the second is `Délai de reconnection`.

My code only concatenates the two first sheets, t does not take under consideration the name of the sheet.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os,sys,inspect

d2 = 'C:/Users/khouloud/Desktop/cleanVersion/Reports'
d1 = 'C:/Users/khouloud/Desktop/Reports'

output_dir =FinalResult

file_d1 = glob.glob(d1 + "/*.xlsx")
file_d2 = glob.glob(d2 + "/*.xlsx")
i=0
#  
for file_d1 in glob.glob(d1 + "/*.xlsx"):
    fileName_d1 = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_d1))[0])[0]       
    for file_d2 in glob.glob(d2 + "/*.xlsx"):
        fileName_d2 = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_d2))[0])[0]
        if fileName_d1 == fileName_d2:
            i+=1
            fileName_1=d1+'/'+fileName_d1+'.xlsx'
            df1 = pd.read_excel(fileName_1, header=0, index= False)
            fileName_2=d2+'/'+fileName_d2+'.xlsx'
            df2 = pd.read_excel(fileName_2, header=0, index= False)
            df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([df1.values, df2.values]), columns=df2.columns)
            print('**********************************************')
            print(df)
            print('**********************************************')
            df.to_excel(FinalResult+'/'+fileName+'/'+fileName_d1+'.xlsx', index = False, header=True)
```

Comment: For this use case, pandas may not be the best choice. You can use openpyxl to read the excel files and xlsxwriter to write a combined excel file with good control on how it looks. (or use pandas to read the excel, but use xlsxwriter to write it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something this?

```
rd1 = pd.read_excel(filename1, sheet_name = 'Rapport détaillé')
ddr = pd.read_excel(filename1, sheet_name = 'Délai de reconnection')
rd2 = pd.read_excel(filename2, sheet_name = 'Rapport détaillé')
rd_comb = pd.concat([rd1,rd2])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(target_file_name, 
engine='xlsxwriter')
rd_comb .to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Rapport détaillé')
ddr.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Délai de reconnection')
writer.save()
```

In the past I've had issues with sheetname vs sheet_name depending on versions.

Comment: with `Python 3.x` we use  `sheet_name`